# Python Input Validation [Functions]

Tags: python, function, validation

I am asked to make a program that calculates the resultant of a given magnitude and direction..
The program executes the calculation but there seems to be a problem in the validation.. every time I make an input that is more than 360 which is the validation for the direction it will ask me to input again

Problem:
Even though I am inpputing for the magnitude it cannot go outside of 360 and it will keep asking for the direction. Same with my validation for the magnitude that cannot go less than 0 if i inputted a number that is less than 0 it will ask that the DIRECTION have the wrong input even though it should be the magnitude

Code:

```
import math
def main():
    M1,D1 = get_values()
    M2,D2 = get_values()
    RFX = rx(M1,M2,D1,D2)
    RFY = ry(M1,M2,D1,D2)
    ResultantMagnitude = resultant(RFX,RFY)
    ResultantDirection = direction_r(RFY,RFX)
    display(ResultantMagnitude,ResultantDirection)
def get_values():
    print('\nPlease input the needed values for the resultant \n ')
    D = float (input('Direction of Force = '))
    D = validate_direction(D)
    M = float (input('Magnitude of Force = '))
    M = validate_direction(M)
    return M,D
def validate_direction(Dz):
    while Dz > 360 or Dz < 0:
        print("Invalid Direction, enter again : ")
        Dz=float(input())
    return Dz
def validate_magnitude(Mz):
    while Mz < 0:
        print("Invalid Magnitude, enter again : ")
        Mz=float(input())
    return Mz
def rx(M1,M2,D1,D2):
    #Force 1
    if D1 <= 90 or D1 == 360:
        F1x = ((M1 * math.cos(math.radians(D1))))
    elif D1 <= 180 or D1 > 90:
        F1x = ((abs(M1)* math.cos(math.radians(D1))))
    elif D1 <= 270 or D1 >180:
        F1x = ((M1 * math.cos(math.radians(D1))))
    else:
        F1x = ((M1 * math.cos(math.radians(D1))))
    #force 2
    if D2 <= 90 or D2 == 360:
        F2x = ((M2 * math.cos(math.radians(D2))))
    elif D2 <= 180 or D2 > 90:
        F2x = ((abs(M2)* math.cos(math.radians(D2))))
    elif D2 <= 270 or D2 >180:
        F2x = ((M2 * math.cos(math.radians(D2))))
    else:
        F2x = ((M2 * math.cos(math.radians(D2))))
    RFX = (F1x + F2x)
    return RFX
def ry(M1,M2,D1,D2):
    #Force 1
    if D1 <= 90 or D1 == 360:
        F1y = (M1 * math.sin(math.radians(D1)))
    elif D1 <= 180 or D1 > 90:
        F1y = (abs(M1) * math.sin(math.radians(D1)))
    elif D1 <= 270 or D1 >180:
        F1y = (M1 * math.sin(math.radians(D1)))
    else:
        F1y = (abs(M1) * math.sin(math.radians(D1)))
    #force 2
    if D2 <= 90 or D2 == 360:
        F2y = (M2 * math.sin(math.radians(D2)))
    elif D2 <= 180 or D2 > 90:
        F2y = (abs(M2) * math.sin(math.radians(D2)))
    elif D2 <= 270 or D2 >180:
        F2y = (M2 * math.sin(math.radians(D2)))
    else:
        F2y = (abs(M2) * math.sin(math.radians(D2)))
    RFY = (F1y + F2y)
    return RFY
def resultant(RFX,RFY):
    ResultantMagnitude = (math.sqrt((pow(RFX,2) + pow(RFY,2))))
    return ResultantMagnitude
def direction_r(RFY,RFX):
    if RFY == 0:
        RFY = 1
        if RFX == 0:
            RFX = 1

    ResultantDirection =math.degrees(math.atan((RFY)/(RFX)))
    return ResultantDirection
def display(ResultantMagnitude,ResultantDirection):
    print('\n')
    print('The magnitude of the resultant is {:0.2f}'.format(ResultantMagnitude), 'Newton')
    print('The direction of the resultant is {:0.2f}'.format(ResultantDirection) , 'Degrees')


x="Y"
while(x!="N"):
    main()
    x=input("Press Y to continue, N to stop : ").upper()
```

Output:

```
Please input the needed values for the resultant

Direction of Force = 200
Magnitude of Force = 2000
Invalid Direction, enter again :
200

Please input the needed values for the resultant

Direction of Force = 200
Magnitude of Force = -200
Invalid Direction, enter again :
200


The magnitude of the resultant is 400.00 Newton
The direction of the resultant is 20.00 Degrees
Press Y to continue, N to stop :
```

Comment: You call "validate_direction" twice in "get_values".

Comment: You have my deepest gratitude Butscher, I'm this close to dropping this course, if I can't notice that small hiccup i don't think i'm fit for being a programmer

Comment: When learning something new, you have to concentrate on many little things which are later, with more experience, done nearly automatically. Therefore you may oversee things in the beginning and make mistakes which won't happen anymore later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling twice the validate_direction() function. you should call validate_magnitude() for the M.